# request.POST empty for Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

Tags: django, post, request, content-type

**[SOLVED] Please see my answer.**

Any `POST` request sent with the 
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY` results in the `request.POST` `QueryDict{}` to be empty. Changing the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` also results in the same error.

Removing the Content-Type altogether results in the values getting passed correctly, and I can access them in `request.POST`.

I have tried disabling the Csrf middleware, using @csrf_exempt, and also tried the same on multiple servers. Didn't change the empty POST condition.

While reading up on Django framework and POST content-type, I read that it (no longer) assumes a default content-type and therefore must be supplied with the correct one (I do not have a link to the article in question.) I think something similar is happening here, with django not being able to parse the parameters with the given content-type (but leaving it blank lets the parser interpret it with the default value).

What I am having trouble with is, that the Content-Type value supplied is perfectly valid (multipart/form-data with boundary). So why does django refuse to load it in the POST dictionary?

** I am not in control of the Content-Type sent in the POST data.

** UPDATE: reading from `request.body` shows that all the `POST` parameters are being received. They're just not present in `request.POST`

** UPDATE: I'm using Runscope to test `POST` requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the *UPDATE*, I was using **Runscope** to test the `POST` data. I realised that the error was with the way Runscope handled `multipart/form-data`. I raised the issue with support and got notified that Runscope does not support multipart as of now. I've copied the relevant information here:

> We hope to support multipart form uploads capabilities for the future, but don't have a timeline on when this will be available. Some customers have made this work in their Radar tests (https://www.runscope.com/docs/radar) by pasting in the raw multipart-formatted body or unicode string input body into the request and making sure to include the applicable 'Content-type' header value with the correct boundaries. Some examples for building a multipart/form-data POST request can be found here: http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html
>
> For Runscope URLs, multipart data is passed through unmodified. However, the request editor and retries from the Traffic Inspector (https://www.runscope.com/docs/inspector) do not currently support multipart data which is why your request retry did not work. Additionally, request and response bodies larger than 1 MB are not saved for viewing after the request has been sent.

Using another service solved this for me.

Comment: sorry for the confusion on multipart! this is definitely something we want to support better in the future. what service did you end up using?

Comment: @Runscope Thanks for your support. I used `hurl.it` for a quick fix. That being said, I found that Runscope has much better tools. I wish Runscope would sort this out soon.

Answer (score 0):

You are (in a manner) in control of `Content-Type`. What you're looking for is `enctype`. You can use it as following:

```
<form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`enctype` is only required when you are uploading a file, otherwise, it's not.

Comment: No, I meant the `Content-Type` field received in `POST` data. `enctype` is a client-side notation that tells what encoding should be sent to the server. Also, I'm not in control of the encoding/type of POST data being sent to the server.